# Back button android is not overridden in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

Hey guys i am developing a mobile application using phonegap and i am trying to prevent the back button from going back to the previous page i just want it not to do anything or actually to remain in the same page not affecting the page i am in .. to make it more easier i just want to disable such default behaviour of the back button and i tried to use this way below in javascript and it didn't work for me is there any other solution for this please let me know ...
Thank you in advance ..

```js
//Thats how i override the backbutton and its not working !!//

document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {

    alert('no back button activity');
}
```